# Enabling PUSH notification in existing uploaded application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have a application uploaded on App store that doesn't use PUSH notification as of now.
I want to enable PUSH notifications in the application and push that as a part of App upgrade in the store. I went through a POC for PUSH notification and it states to create SSL certificate and a provisioning profile and use them for development.

Here is the tutorial that i refered http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

I wanted to clarify if i can enable PUSH notifications in existing application without revoking the old certificate and will it affect my application in anyway? I maybe a bit confused here on the ssl certificates and app certificates.
Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can Enable APNS without Affecting App store Application.
2. Its Same step for Making APNS SSl Creation.
3. You Need to Upload App with New Version after Making APNS enabled Application.
4. You can edit and Use Old Provisioning profile for App Upgrade.

Referencer Link:

Please Check this Reference for Making SSL and APNS setup.

[Easy APNS](http://www.easyapns.com/)

Comment: Help me out here, so i do not need to touch the existing development/distribution certificate, but i need to edit the old App ID to include the enable the PUSH notification and create a new Distribution Provisioning profile with the edited App id. I am correct?