# IOS How can I get csr file for already deployed App

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I have already submitted the application in Appstore, now I need to enable push notification on the app and submit as new version. I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) to implement remote push notification. Based on the answer here [Enabling PUSH notification in existing uploaded application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519153/enabling-push-notification-in-existing-uploaded-application) I understand that I can do it on already published App, So as a first step I have edited the App ID of the application with push notification enabled on Member center. Now I need to generate the SSL certificate, for that it requires the  the CSR file upload to the member center.
But I have no idea where it's locate in my PC,

Comment: You can't locate it on your PC, because that's the file to be generated. You can generate CSR file using `OpenSSL` as described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902030/making-csr-certificates-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you should probably save it going forward.  The good news is, if you have the private key that was used for your distribution certificate, you can use that to generate the CSR.  To find out if you have the private key, you can use this post for how to locate it in the Keychain app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33651921/3708242

Once you have verified that you have the private key used for the certificate for the app store distribution, you can generate the a CSR using the following procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111454/3708242